# Why is my Bootstrap [4.2] Navbar Toggler not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a responsive Navbar with Bootstrap Version 4.2 (I know its "old") but somehow it isn't working as expected. When I click on the hamburger symbol, nothing happens. Can anyone look after the mistake I made in the code below?
I googled a lot, checked the script order, but nothing worked.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vSIIfh2YWi9wW0r9iZe7RJPrKwp6bG+s9QZMoITbCckVJqGCCRhc+ccxNcdpHuYu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Own CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="./css/style.css">
<title>Website Title</title>

<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Blogtopia</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" date-target="#navbarcollapse" aria-controls="navbarcollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarcollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./MyProfile.php" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> My Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Dashboard.php" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Posts.php" class="nav-link">Posts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Categories.php" class="nav-link">Categories</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Admins.php" class="nav-link">Manage Admins</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Comments.php" class="nav-link">Comments</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Blog.php?page=1" class="nav-link">Live Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Logout.php" class="nav-link text-danger"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Bootstrap Javascript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: @SoJs, how is docs for a different version helpful?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/navbar-static/ copy and paste source.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

It's a **typo** – you wrote `date-target`
, but it should be `data-target`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vSIIfh2YWi9wW0r9iZe7RJPrKwp6bG+s9QZMoITbCckVJqGCCRhc+ccxNcdpHuYu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Blogtopia</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcollapse" aria-controls="navbarcollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarcollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./MyProfile.php" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> My Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Dashboard.php" class="nav-link">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Posts.php" class="nav-link">Posts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Categories.php" class="nav-link">Categories</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Admins.php" class="nav-link">Manage Admins</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Comments.php" class="nav-link">Comments</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Blog.php?page=1" class="nav-link">Live Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="./Logout.php" class="nav-link text-danger"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didnt realise it. Thanks.